# Django and direct database manipulation

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I have a project where the client has to log in to the database and manually do the data entry there. Yes,direct access,don't ask why!

What I want is when I apply the changes to the table,the created and modified field to be auto-copleted with current date and time.

I am using MySQL.

So I have created my model as so..

```
class Atlantis(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField('description', max_length=200 ,  default = None,null=True,blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField('Amount', default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0)
    inserted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    update_chk = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' On save, update timestamps '''
    if not self.id:
        self.created = timezone.now()
    self.modified = timezone.now()
    return super(Atlantis, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I add data to the database the created field isn't being auto-completed with current timestamp.

I tried to alter the table in the database and change the default setting for created field to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,but there was an error.

So I am asking, can what I am asking be done?

Comment: When you say add data do you mean by doing it directly without the orm? What was the error?

Comment: The user has to entry the data directly to the database table.
The error was: ERROR 1067: Invalid default value for 'created'.
I tried to put CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: If theyre doing it directly to the db then there is absolutely nothing django can do.

Comment: I don't want django to do it. I want MySQL to do it. As soon as the user hits 'apply' and the sql statement runs INSERT INTO `db_name`.`db_table` (`table_column`) VALUES ('some value');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I altered the mySQL table... And changed the datetime field to timestamp.  Django reads it as timestamp.  So no problems there.  It was the version of mySQL that caused the problem.  Couldn't use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default with datetime field.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem try this:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
  self._meta.local_fields = [f for f in self._meta.local_fields if f.name not in ('your_field')]
  super(Atlantis, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

It helps for me